# Separate the below code in server.go and client.go

Tags: go, ssl, tls1.2

I have found this code online which generates the TLS cert and key dynamically and registers it, also when I run this I am able to connect successfully.

```
package main
 
import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "crypto/x509/pkix"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/big"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "time"
)
 
func main() {
    // get our ca and server certificate
    serverTLSConf, clientTLSConf, err := certsetup()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
 
    // set up the httptest.Server using our certificate signed by our CA
    server := httptest.NewUnstartedServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "success!")
    }))
    server.TLS = serverTLSConf
    server.StartTLS()
    defer server.Close()
 
    // communicate with the server using an http.Client configured to trust our CA
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: clientTLSConf,
    }
    http := http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }
    resp, err := http.Get(server.URL)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
 
    // verify the response
    respBodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    body := strings.TrimSpace(string(respBodyBytes[:]))
    if body == "success!" {
        fmt.Println(body)
    } else {
        panic("not successful!")
    }
}
 
func certsetup() (serverTLSConf *tls.Config, clientTLSConf *tls.Config, err error) {
    // set up our CA certificate
    ca := &x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(2019),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization:  []string{"Company, INC."},
            Country:       []string{"US"},
            Province:      []string{""},
            Locality:      []string{"San Francisco"},
            StreetAddress: []string{"Golden Gate Bridge"},
            PostalCode:    []string{"94016"},
        },
        NotBefore:             time.Now(),
        NotAfter:              time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        IsCA:                  true,
        ExtKeyUsage:           []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth, x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        KeyUsage:              x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature | x509.KeyUsageCertSign,
        BasicConstraintsValid: true,
    }
 
    // create our private and public key
    caPrivKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 4096)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
 
    // create the CA
    caBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, ca, ca, &caPrivKey.PublicKey, caPrivKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
 
    // pem encode
    caPEM := new(bytes.Buffer)
    pem.Encode(caPEM, &pem.Block{
        Type:  "CERTIFICATE",
        Bytes: caBytes,
    })
 
    caPrivKeyPEM := new(bytes.Buffer)
    pem.Encode(caPrivKeyPEM, &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(caPrivKey),
    })
 
    // set up our server certificate
    cert := &x509.Certificate{
        SerialNumber: big.NewInt(2019),
        Subject: pkix.Name{
            Organization:  []string{"Company, INC."},
            Country:       []string{"US"},
            Province:      []string{""},
            Locality:      []string{"San Francisco"},
            StreetAddress: []string{"Golden Gate Bridge"},
            PostalCode:    []string{"94016"},
        },
        IPAddresses:  []net.IP{net.IPv4(127, 0, 0, 1), net.IPv6loopback},
        NotBefore:    time.Now(),
        NotAfter:     time.Now().AddDate(10, 0, 0),
        SubjectKeyId: []byte{1, 2, 3, 4, 6},
        ExtKeyUsage:  []x509.ExtKeyUsage{x509.ExtKeyUsageClientAuth, x509.ExtKeyUsageServerAuth},
        KeyUsage:     x509.KeyUsageDigitalSignature,
    }
 
    certPrivKey, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 4096)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
 
    certBytes, err := x509.CreateCertificate(rand.Reader, cert, ca, &certPrivKey.PublicKey, caPrivKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
 
    certPEM := new(bytes.Buffer)
    pem.Encode(certPEM, &pem.Block{
        Type:  "CERTIFICATE",
        Bytes: certBytes,
    })
 
    certPrivKeyPEM := new(bytes.Buffer)
    pem.Encode(certPrivKeyPEM, &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(certPrivKey),
    })
 
    serverCert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(certPEM.Bytes(), certPrivKeyPEM.Bytes())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
 
    serverTLSConf = &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{serverCert},
    }
 
    certpool, _ := x509.SystemCertPool()
    if certpool == nil {
        certpool = x509.NewCertPool()
    }
    certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caPEM.Bytes())
    clientTLSConf = &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify: true,
    }
 
    return
}
```

now how do i separate it in 2 files like server.go and client.go

here it uses  httptest.NewUnstartedServer instead of that I would like to use ListenAndServeTLS or some similar method how can I achieve that.

Comment: what have you tried? There's a clear section dealing with `client` and `server`.

Comment: Just but some code into server.go  and the rest into client.go ?

Comment: Hi @shreyas. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm reviewing your question as a new contributor. May I suggest some changes to your question?
1) Could you explain why you are stuck? What led you to want to ask this question? What makes this hard for you to do?
2) Explain why you are trying to separate the code into two files?
3) Are you new to Golang? New to programming itself? Explain these points.
4) Rephrase so your question comes first, i.e. "now how do i separate it in 2 files like server.go and client.go". Also make sure your title reflects the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

For refactoring your code into server.go and client.go you first need to know which part goes where and also how you access it from your main or another service. In the following article you are able to find a decent explenation for refactoring code. https://medium.com/@elliotchance/a-new-simpler-way-to-do-dependency-injection-in-go-9e191bef50d5

I assume you would like to use the function ListenAndServeTLS from the http package (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/).

Make sure you check the input types and pass them into the function.
`func ListenAndServeTLS(addr, certFile, keyFile string, handler Handler) error`

If you are not familiar with interfaces and handlers check this article out. https://medium.com/@matryer/the-http-handler-wrapper-technique-in-golang-updated-bc7fbcffa702